# Are questions about campus facilities on-topic?

Tags: support

I have a question that is not a problem, but rather something that I'm curious about and could elicit a good answer. I would like to know the reasons for what I believe is a trend relating to the kinds of facilities offered by campuses.

It's not about academia per se, but I think it *could* fall under the [allowed topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of

> Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor

and maybe even

> Inner workings of research departments.

Comment: There's no high-level reason it would be off-topic that I can see. Give it a shot.

Comment: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20669/why-do-campuses-have-glass-blowing-services

Answer (score 5):

Questions on university facilities should be on-topic if they pertain directly (as you point out) to "life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor" etc.

Questions about facilities that aren't specific to academia or academic life (e.g., "What kind of lighting is best for an office environment?") would probably be off topic as "boat programming" questions.

We've had some questions related to facilities before:

- [What are some good ways to provide computer labs for the students?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17200/what-are-some-good-ways-to-provide-computer-labs-for-the-students)
- [Best practices for keeping a campus computer network from getting brought down by inappropriate use?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17859/best-practices-for-keeping-a-campus-computer-network-from-getting-brought-down-b)

Comment: FWIW, [workplace.SE] probably covers many questions that may occur in the context of but are not specific to academia or campuses.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add that I think this should be limited to a campus's **academic** facilities.  For the question at hand, a glass shop directly supports a university's academic mission (by producing equipment for research) so it's fine to ask about here.  The same can be said for computer labs and networks.

But campuses have lots of other facilities, and I wouldn't support a question about a university's dorms, cafeterias, swimming pools, squash courts, medical clinics, parking garages, boiler plants, or electrical substations.  These may affect the lives of students and professors, but I don't think they should be on-topic here.  I don't see this community as having the relevant expertise.